# How to crop the unused canvas space from a saved base64 image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, base64

Is there a way to crop a base64 image prior to saving?

[image]

- Currently I use a **html5** canvas to create an image.
- The entire canvas is saved which is inefficient.
- The canvas is resizable and I would like to know if the unused
  **transparant pixels** can be cropped from the saved image.

---

**JAVASCRIPT (JQUERY)**

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('Pad'),
    save = wrapper.querySelector('[data-btn=save]'),
    canvas = wrapper.querySelector('canvas'),
    pad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

function resizeCanvas() {
  var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
  canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
resizeCanvas();
```

Canvas save to dataUrl function:

```
save.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
  $('txtbx').val(dataUrl);
});
```

Comment: Could you give a hint on how you build your image ? Because it *might* be simpler to draw on a new canvas having just the right size then save this one.

Comment: @GameAlchemist See edits above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, here's one way:**

- Use `context.getImageData` to get the RGBA pixel array of the canvas.
- Note: transparent pixels have alpha array value == 0;
- Examine each row of pixels from the top downward and get the first non-transparent row (var top);
- Examine each row of pixels from the bottom upward and get the first non-transparent row (var bottom);
- Examine each column of pixels from the left rightward and get the first non-transparent column (var left);
- Examine each column of pixels from the right lefward and get the first non-transparent column (var right);
- Create an in-memory canvas and size it using the calculated values:

  ```
  var width=right-left;
  var height=bottom-top;

  var canvas1=document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas1.width=width;
  canvas1.height=height;
  ```
- Draw just the non-transparent pixels on the in-memory canvas

  ```
  var ctx1=canvas1.getContext('2d');

  // clip just the non-transparent pixels and draw them to the in-memory canvas
  ctx1.drawImage(yourOnScreeCanvas, left,top,width,height, 0,0,width,height);
  ```
- Save the in-memory canvas to an image.

Comment: Chuckle! '@Thou art amazing' found a script that does what I'm suggesting here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

try https://gist.github.com/remy/784508

It finds empty pixels and based on their position, it crops the image